# How to extract the partition values from the cld() function in kml package

Tags: r

I am attempting to extract the partition values from the `cld()` function in `kml` package. The data is longitudinal (5 points) and from 7 tokens. When I use the `cld()` function, it gives me the partitions in a plot where I can see the lines (red and green in the plot). However, I want to find a way (specifically, a line code) that allows me to extract the x,y coordinates of these two lines, which will later be used for analysis and plotting somewhere else. For example, the y-coordinates for the red line are: `c(74, 79, 78, 80, 79)`. Here I give the code and the plot generated.

```
#Code
library(kml)
points = rep(1:5, 7)

values = c(92.33181,90.34771,90.16533,89.54722,89.30509,85.27513,85.84612,83.80208,82.08371,82.65119,
           81.36381,83.33078,82.72064,83.22167,82.39488,82.58548,82.54190,79.45408,78.29970,77.89541,
           64.91261,77.20562,79.44067,82.22554,81.84798,87.33230,86.07741,88.16766,87.85872,87.23672,
           83.27685,82.20176,85.21291,84.76475,84.23799)

tokens = rep(1:7, each = 5)

df = data.frame(points, values, tokens)

#clustering of the data
df.cluster <- reshape(df, timevar="points", idvar="tokens", direction="wide")
names(df.cluster) <- c("id", paste("t", 1:(ncol(df.cluster)-1)))
df.cluster.cld <- cld(df.cluster)
kml(df.cluster.cld, nbClusters=2, nbRedrawing=1)

#plot
choice(df.cluster.cld)
```

[image: Plot generated]

All I can see is this when I inspect the element `df.cluster.cld`, but it does not seem to show what I am looking for.

```
print(df.cluster.cld)

~~~ Class: ClusterLongData ~~~
      ~ Sub-Class: LongData ~ 
~ idAll       = [7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
~ idFewNA     = [7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
~ varNames    = [1] V
~ time        = [5] 1 2 3 4 5
~ maxNA       = [1] 3
~ reverse     = [2x1]
    - mean    = 0
    - SD      = 1

~ traj = [7x5] (limited to 5x10)  :
        t1       t2       t3       t4       t5
1 92.33181 90.34771 90.16533 89.54722 89.30509
2 85.27513 85.84612 83.80208 82.08371 82.65119
3 81.36381 83.33078 82.72064 83.22167 82.39488
4 82.58548 82.54190 79.45408 78.29970 77.89541
5 64.91261 77.20562 79.44067 82.22554 81.84798
... ...

    ~ Sub-Class: ListPartition ~ 
 ~ criterionActif          =  Calinski.Harabatz
 ~ initializationMethod    =  kmeans-
 ~ sorted                  =  TRUE
 ~ criterion values (Calinski.Harabatz):
    -  c2  : 4.851811
```

Comment: Use `str` to explore the content of objects. My quick look revealed that `df.cluster.cld@time` gives you the x values, but I couldn't find the y values. `df.cluster.cld@c2[[1]]@postProba` gives posterior probabilities (?), perhaps the y values are calculated in the plot function? Also see `?'ClusterLongData-class'`.

Comment: Hi @Axeman, thank you very mucn for your insightful answer. I had a look at the `?'ClusterLongData-class'` and I could not find the y values. As you have suggested, the y values might be calculated in the plot function, but I have not been able to find it. I keep searching. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to do the same (extracting the mean trajectories for the clusters) and looking at the code of the function that plots the trajectories (the plot you show in your question), I got the line that does exactly that. In case it's still useful, here is the code:

```
# Substitute the 'c2' for the number of clusters in your case
# 1 in the second argument is the number of the partition you're looking at    
mean.trajectories <- calculTrajMean(df.cluster.cld["traj"], df.cluster.cld['c2'][[1]]['clusters'])
```

calculTrajMean is a function within the 'kml' package, I just did not know how to relate it with extracting the trajectories from my clusters. The idea was to look the code of the plot function within the 'kml' package, which calls another function, which calls the function plotTrajMeans from the 'longitudinal' package and the line was there. 
What you get is a matrix with nrow=number of clusters and ncol=number of time points of your trajectories.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! 'kml' is a very interesting package. If you're happy with the answer, could you accept it? Thanks!